# Challenge: Describe your country's academic idiosyncrasies in its tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a number of country- and continent-specific tags on Academia.SE:

- [united-states](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)
- [europe](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe)
- [united-kingdom](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)
- [india](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india)
- [asia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asia)
- [switzerland](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switzerland)
- [germany](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany)
- [france](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/france)
- [sweden](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sweden)
- [japan](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan)
- [new-zealand](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-zealand)

(feel free to add any existing "country" tags I missed).

These tags are used alongside other tags when asking about conventions or academic systems that are specific to a particular country.

Some, like [Europe](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/europe/info) and [Germany](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany), have excellent tag wikis that describe in some detail the specific quirks of that country's academic system. Others... not so much.

If you are personally familiar with a particular academic system, please take a moment to look over its tag wiki and fill in these details.

Answer (score 3):

I think the [asia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asia) and [europe](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) tags are pretty useless. There is just too much variability across the contents to make the tags useful. A few questions from the [europe](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) tag (e.g., the ones on FP7 funding and ECTS) might be better served by the [eu](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu) tag.

Comment: I agree, but I think this is a subtly different issue to the question - might I suggest making it a new Meta question?